# Am having issues while trying to use php artisan preset react

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5

I keep getting "Command preset is no defined" while running php artisan preset react

Havent tried anything yet

php artisan preset react

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel ReactJSLaravelTutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around it... Update Your laravel to any version higher than 5.4 n you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel version less than 5.5 then you may get this error. Because `php artisan preset react` is available from laravel version 5.5. 
Just create new project by following these steps:
  - Simply create new project with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName`.
 - Then change directory with `cd projectName`
 - Then use `php artisan preset react`
 - Next, run the `npm install` command to install app dependencies.